# Integrating OSRM Code with XCode Application

Tags: xcode, undefined, symbols, osrm

I am trying to link Open Source Routing Machine (OSRM) code with a basic command-line application in XCode and run the code provided in Example.cpp (from osrm-master directory) as the main function. I am able to link header files from OSRM 'include' as well as all other required libraries, so within the code, there are no identified errors. However, when I run the project, I get the following error:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "osrm::OSRM::OSRM(osrm::engine::EngineConfig&)", referenced from: _main in main.o "osrm::OSRM::~OSRM()", referenced from: _main in main.o "osrm::OSRM::Route(osrm::engine::api::RouteParameters const&, osrm::util::json::Object&) const", referenced from: _main in main.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Why might this be and how could I approach solving this error? Is there a way you could recommend to link OSRM file system into my application? I don't want to link the library itself (libosrm.a), but the actual source code files.